Stub-Based Unit Testing 5 Read Routines (revision)
This is a follow up to: Stub-Based Unit Testing 5 Read Routines.
What's Changed:
OP's goal of reducing the source files' count has been achieved. There is now a single test source instead of 18 duplicative ones.
Now I have ended up with a general template I am using for all 5 read routines:
test_readlines_failure.c:
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2008'19L    // '
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <stdio.h>

#include "cread/src/FileBuf.h"

#include "cread/test/acutest.h"
#include "cread/test/stubs.c"

#ifdef WITH_FREAD
    #define TESTME readlines_fread
    #include "cread/src/readlines_fread.c"
#elifdef WITH_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_getline
    #include "cread/src/readlines_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_getline
    #include "cread/src/readlines_getline.c"
    #include "cread/src/readlines_mmap_getline.c"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
    #define TESTME readlines_mmap_memchr
    #include "cread/src/readlines_mmap_memchr.c"
#elifdef WITH_READ
    #define TESTME readlines_read
    #include "cread/src/readlines_read.c"
#else
    #error "You need to specify one of WITH_FREAD, WITH_GETLINE,"
           "WITH_MMAP_GETLINE, WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR, or WITH_READ."
#endif

#define STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)       #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)                STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)

#define CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
#define CONCAT(a, b, c)             CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)

void CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure)(void)
{
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/stubs.c", "r");
    TEST_ASSERT(fp);
    TEST_CHECK(!TESTME(fp, &(FileBuf) {}));
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_"  STRINGIFY(TESTME) "_failure",  CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _failure) },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

along with another source file for testing the actual functionality:
test_readlines_success:
#undef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#undef _XOPEN_SOURCE

#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2008'09L    // '
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE   700

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "cread/test/acutest.h"

#include "cread/src/FileBuf.h"

#ifdef WITH_FREAD
    #define TESTME  readlines_fread
    #include "cread/src/readlines_fread.h"
#elifdef WITH_GETLINE
    #define TESTME  readlines_getline
    #include "cread/src/readlines_getline.h"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
    #define TESTME  readlines_mmap_getline
    #include "cread//src/readlines_getline.h"
    #include "cread/src/readlines_mmap_getline.h"
#elifdef WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
    #define TESTME  readlines_mmap_memchr
    #include "cread/src/readlines_mmap_memchr.h"
#elifdef WITH_READ
    #define TESTME  readlines_read
    #include "cread/src/readlines_read.h"
#else
    #error "You need to specify one of WITH_FREAD, WITH_GETLINE,"
           "WITH_MMAP_GETLINE, WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR, or WITH_READ."
#endif

#define STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)       #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)                STRINGIFY_INDIRECT(x)

#define CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)    a ## b ## c
#define CONCAT(a, b, c)             CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b, c)

void CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _success)(void)
{
    /* The lines and line lengths are at most 1024 in sample1.txt. */
    char buf[1024];
    char *lines[1024];
    size_t line_count = 0;
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/sample.txt", "r");

    TEST_ASSERT(fp);

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        TEST_ASSERT((lines[line_count] = strdup(buf)));
        ++line_count;
    }
    
    rewind(fp);

    FileBuf fbuf = {};

    TEST_CHECK(TESTME(fp, &fbuf));
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.count == 555);
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.size == 120635);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fbuf.count; ++i) {
        TEST_CHECK((strcmp(lines[i], fbuf.lines[i].line) == 0));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_"  STRINGIFY(TESTME) "_success",  CONCAT(test_, TESTME, _success) },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

And this is how I build the test executables:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DFEOF $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_fread_feof_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DRESIZE_FBUF $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_fread_resize_fbuf_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD -DALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_fread_alloc_and_append_line_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_FREAD $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_fread.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_fread_success

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_GETLINE -DGETLINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_getline_getline_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_GETLINE -DRESIZE_FBUF $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_getline_resize_fbuf_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_GETLINE -DAPPEND_LINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_getline_append_line_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_GETLINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_getline.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_getline_success

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_MEMCHR -DFSTAT $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_fstat_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_MEMCHR -DMMAP $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_mmap_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_MEMCHR -DRESIZE_FBUF $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_resize_fbuf_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_MEMCHR -DAPPEND_LINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_append_line_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_MEMCHR $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_mmap_memchr.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_success

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_GETLINE -DFSTAT $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_fstat_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_GETLINE -DMMAP $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_mmap_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_GETLINE -DFMEMOPEN $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_fmemopen_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_GETLINE -DGETLINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_readlines_getline_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_MMAP_GETLINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_getline.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_mmap_getline.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_success

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_READ -DFILENO $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_read_fstat_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_READ -DREAD $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_read_mmap_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_READ -DRESIZE_FBUF $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_read_resize_fbuf_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_READ -DALLOC_AND_APPEND_LINE $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_read_append_line_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DWITH_READ $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_read.o $(TEST_SRC_DIR)/test_readlines_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_read_success

which builds 23 separate test executables, but appears grotesque.
Review Request:
I was wondering whether to make a list of all the options in the makefile and then loop over it, or create new small .c files like:
#define WITH_FREAD
#include "test_readlines_success.c"

#undef WITH_FREAD
#define WITH_GETLINE
#include "test_readlines_success.c"

#undef WITH_GETLINE
#define WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
#include "test_readlines_success.c"

#undef WITH_MMAP_GETLINE
#define WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
#include "test_readlines_success.c"

#undef WITH_MMAP_MEMCHR
#define WITH_READ
#include "test_readlines_success.c"

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_readlines_fread_success", test_readlines_fread_success },
    { "test_readlines_getline_success", test_readlines_getline_success },
    { "test_readlines_mmap_getline_success", test_readlines_mmap_getline_success },
    { "test_readlines_mmap_memchr_success", test_readlines_mmap_memchr_success },
    { "test_readlines_read_success", test_readlines_read_success },
};

and then end up with 6 test executable with these build commands:
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_fread_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN)/test_readlines_fread_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_getline_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN)/test_readlines_getline_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN)/test_readlines_mmap_memchr_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN)/test_readlines_mmap_getline_failure
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_read_failure.c -o $(TEST_BIN)/test_readlines_read_failure

$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_DIR)/common.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_fread.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_getline.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_mmap_memchr.o 
$(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_mmap_getline.o $(OBJ_DIR)/readlines_read.o $(TEST_DIR)/test_readlines_all_success.c -o $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_readlines_all_success

I haven't yet tried either solution, and am not sure if the latter would work fine.
But how would you solve this and which solution would you prefer? Or do you have another solution altogether?
